# Photo manager - alternative to Picasa

Tags: windows, photography, information-management, digital-asset-management

I have hundreds of thousands photos on a NAS in the inhouse network. So far I've been using Picasa + mapped folders to Picasa's database, so that it would access exactly same database and photo folders on a network shares, from several computers on the network. This actually works fine, to a point (concurrent access is the biggest issue).

I would like to find a replacement (not necessarily free, but shouldn't be many hundreds of dollars), which would:

1. Allow access to same photos (on a network share) from different machines
2. Allow organizing photos into metacollections like Picasa's albums - without physically duplicating image files
3. Have some rating/tagging system, not necessarily very complicated
4. Bonus: Facial recognition, if it is at all possible to hope to find that, like in Picasa
5. Bonus: to be able to import Picasa's database - at least albums, as a one-time thing
6. Bonus: to be able to act (or have some companion/compatible software) as a media server and provide access to metacollections. Simply put: to be able to view collections (not just folders) on a smart tv or some other DLNA-enabled device.

Picasa is an excellent piece of software and manages very large volumes like a champ, but, alas, isn't perfect, plus it looks like Google put a large cross on its future, judging by lack of updates. Besides, not having any mediaserver features or real centralized DB access is just annoying.

The application should be available on Windows, but a self-hosted solution is also acceptable.

Comment: Knowing the brand of NAS would be helpful.

Comment: NAS is a QNAP of some Linux variety, but I am not even talking about hosting something directly on the NAS. I could be quite content with a Windows-based server, accessing NAS as a network map.

Comment: have you looked at [**Piwigo**](http://piwigo.org/)?

Answer (score 2):

Candidates:

IMatch https://www.photools.com/  It's a fairly decent DAM and has provisions for broad use.